# how to enable catalina log in virgo tomcat server 3.6.1

Tags: eclipse-virgo

**Server**: virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.1.RELEASE

**Problem:**
When I try to deploy war file I see this exception:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContainerException: Web application at '/user-services-core' failed to start. Check the logs for more details.
```

The most interesting part is: *Check the logs for more details.*

No Virgo Tomcat Server log file contains required details. I was able to find out that this means that I should check catalina logs. Unfortunately Virgo Tomcat Server does not produce file catalina.log like pure Tomcat server. It only produces file access_log.txt.

**The question:**

How configure Virgo Tomcat Server in order to get catalina.log file or just to find out what is wrong with my war file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the log file in .../virgo/serviceability/logs/log.log? It should also contain output from tomcat (catalina.log).

Comment: Hi James. I've checked that file, in fact presented exception is taken from this file. In my case it was (virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.1.RELEASE\serviceability\logs\log.log). There is nothing what explains cause of this exception :(